# How to dynamically hide a div with the value in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a website where I need to be able to dynamically hide a div based on a number entered in a textbox.

As the user enters "0", I need a div to hide.  If the user enters any other number, I need the div to show.

Is there a way to do that?

I have looked at a lot of examples, but they are all based around sorting or using a filter which is completely different than what I am wanting.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshchitlangia/qzkm8cft/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
    This Div will be hidden when you enter zero.
</div>

<input type="text" id="userInput"/>
```

JQuery

```
$('#userInput').on('input',function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 0 )
        $('#myDiv').hide();
    else
        $('#myDiv').show();
});
```

Explanation:
`.on()` is used to attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Here is the syntax:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

For more details on this function refer the [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on `change` event. You can use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** function for binding events.

```
$('yourInputSelector').on('input',function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 0 )
        $('yourDiv').show();
    else
        $('yourDiv').show();
});
```